# Multiply a loop in java script

Tags: javascript, debugging

so i need to multiply every number in this loop i've created but its not coming out the way it should

```
//declare all variables
var enteredNumber;
var biggerEnteredNumber;
var totalValue;
var totalEnteredNumbers;

//Assign variables
   totalEnteredNumbers = 0;

//Ask user for two numbers and the second to be bigger than the first
    enteredNumber = prompt("Enter a number");
    enteredNumber = Number(enteredNumber);

    biggerEnteredNumber = prompt("Enter a number bigger than the first number");
    biggerEnteredNumber = Number(biggerEnteredNumber);

for (enteredNumber = 1; enteredNumber < biggerEnteredNumber; enteredNumber++) {
    document.write(enteredNumber + " * ");

    totalEnteredNumbers = enteredNumber;
    totalValue = totalEnteredNumbers * biggerEnteredNumber;
 }

document.write(biggerEnteredNumber + " = " + totalValue);
 }
```

if the user enter 3 and 7 how would i multiply 3*4*5*6*7??

Comment: did you tried enteredNumber*=enteredNumber;?
and when you are saying that enteredNumber=1 in for loop that means you have assigned enteredNumber to 1. you must use some othe variable over there.

Comment: Just to make sure, Is this what you want?: The user inputs two values (say `3` and `7`). Multiply each value from `3` to `7` (3*4*5*6*7)? I don't get it what you meant by _multiply the enteredNumber by themseleves_. Or do you want to `3*3` `4*4` `5*5` `6*6` `7*7`? Please, elaborate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @FirstOne yes i'm trying to multiply each value for 3 to 7 if they were to input those two values but idk how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this code (not checking if user really typed a number):

```
//declare all variables
var v1;
var v2;
var total = 1; // start with 1 so mult. doesn't go wrong
var text = "";

//Ask user for two numbers and the second to be bigger than the first
v1 = prompt("Enter a number");
v1 = Number(v1);

do{ // while the second number is not bigger
    v2 = prompt("Enter a number bigger than the first number");
    v2 = Number(v2);
} while(v1 >= v2);

for (i = v1; i <= v2; i++) {
    if(i < v2){
      text += i + " * ";
    }else{
      text += i;
    }

    total = total * i;
 }

alert(text + " = " + total); // 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 = 2520
```

*I changed to alert but it doesn't really matter*.
[Run jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66643138/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
function multiplyvalues(from, to) {
  var result = 0; 
  for(var i = from; i < to; i++) { result += (i * to);}
  console.log(result); 
}
```

finally implement this function in console doing:

multiplyvalues(0, 4);

Answer (score 0):

Not quote sure what you need to multiply, but here are some suggestions you can use. I do the text/appendChild to not user document.write which is blocked here

```js
//declare all variables
var enteredNumber;
var biggerEnteredNumber;
var totalValue;
var totalEnteredNumbers;
var loopCounter; 
var text; 

//Assign variables
totalValue = 0;
text = "";

//Ask user for two numbers and the second to be bigger than the first
enteredNumber = prompt("Enter a number");
enteredNumber = Number(enteredNumber);

biggerEnteredNumber = prompt("Enter a number bigger than the first number");
biggerEnteredNumber = Number(biggerEnteredNumber);

for (loopCounter = 1; loopCounter < biggerEnteredNumber; loopCounter++) {
  text += "<br/>"+loopCounter + " * ";
  totalValue += (loopCounter*enteredNumber);
}

text += "<br/>"+biggerEnteredNumber + " = " + totalValue;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=text;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```